Does Politics SE see more downvotes than other SEs?
Does Politics SE see more downvotes than other SEs, as a proportion of total votes cast?
If yes, is it 1) a problem that should be addressed, 2) a problem that does not need to be addressed, or 3) not a problem?

Somewhat More Downvotes Than Most (but not all)
Based on a quick and dirty SEDE query I wrote while not logged in, Politics is around the 5 up to 1 down mark:
| Site                |        Up |     Down |   Down / Up |   (D/U)/1 |
|---------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------|
| Politics            |    575160 |   113222 |  0.19685305 | 5.0799315 |
| History             |    371700 |    54528 |  0.14669895 | 6.8166814 |
| Skeptics            |    472123 |    61721 |  0.13073076 | 7.6493092 |
| Law                 |    289385 |    45796 |  0.15825285 | 6.3190015 |
| Economics           |     84671 |    13617 |  0.16082248 | 6.2180362 |
| Finance             |    571714 |    66985 |  0.11716523 | 8.5349553 |
| RPG                 |   1551803 |   137667 | 0.088714225 | 11.272149 |
| WebApps             |    278807 |    93328 |  0.33474052 | 2.9873886 |
| Emacs               |    181596 |     3213 | 0.017693121 | 56.519141 |
| Christianity        |    252704 |    65656 |  0.25981385 | 3.8489095 |
| Islam               |     83521 |    48787 |  0.58412854 | 1.7119520 |
| MiYodeya            |    399328 |    53100 |  0.13297340 | 7.5203011 |
| CodeReview          |    805104 |   106668 |  0.13248972 | 7.5477554 |
| SoftwareEngineering |   2123189 |   363594 |  0.17124900 | 5.8394502 |
| AskUbuntu           |   3615360 |   548319 |  0.15166373 | 6.5935343 |
| Mathematics         |   9148778 |  1315657 |  0.14380686 | 6.9537712 |
| TeX                 |   2981781 |    45547 | 0.015275099 | 65.466024 |
| Unix&Linux          |   2702866 |   177019 | 0.065493073 | 15.268790 |
| Academia            |   1388378 |   131589 | 0.094778943 | 10.550867 |
| TheWorkplace        |   1724047 |   217653 |  0.12624540 | 7.9210807 |
|---------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------|
| StackOverflow       | 184390504 | 24869904 |  0.13487627 | 7.4142027 |
| SuperUser           |   3991598 |   612789 |  0.15351972 | 6.5138212 |
| ServerFault         |   2194116 |   306524 |  0.13970273 | 7.1580563 |
|---------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-----------|
| Meta (MSE)          |   2796888 |   830068 |  0.29678271 | 3.3694685 |

Sites 'similar' in metrics (size, questions per day, etc) are gathered near the top of the table. Some bigger sites are towards the bottom above the 'Original Three' section, and Meta gets a section to itself due to voting differences
This is roughly comparable to our sister sites Law and Economics (close to 6 up per 1 down); though History and Skeptics have slightly more upvotes-per-downvote (6.8 and 7.6ish respectively).
Webapps and Christianity have a bigger proportion of downvotes than here.
The closest-ratio site I've found so far is SoftwareEngineering, at 5.8 upvotes per downvote.
Note that voting on SE Meta works differently, but the data is included regardless.
Does anything need done about this?
I don't think any action needs taken. Given how contentious politics is as a subject in general, I think 5 to 1 is a reasonable ratio.

Special mention goes to Emacs and TeX for an average of 56.5 and 65.5 upvotes per downvote respectively!

I added on a few bigger sites, I am happy to add more sites or have others edit them in :)

Meta.SE may not be a fair comparison, as voting works differently for feature-requests: On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.. Otherwise +1. Many sites appear do have a ration of 6-7, so our 5 isn't all that bad, especially given the subject matter.

@xyldke you're absolutely right, I meant to footnote that but got distracted by Emacs' ratio!

I guess key combination for downvote on Emacs is too complicated.

@TadeuszKopec And no-one knows the correct macro to downvote on TeX!

I'm not surprised the ratio is less than on Christianity, but WebApps has even more DVs [per UV]? What's up with that? Out of curiosity, did you also include Islam SE in the query, but did not report it here?

Also, I suppose this table doesn't include DVs on deleted Q&As. Those generally attract most such votes, IIRC.

@gottrolledtoomuchthisweek Webapps has a strange ratio, agreed- maybe they get a lot of strange questions that aren't on topic ? I dunno. I haven't queried Islam SE yet, I can do so and edit them in- Christianity was included as they are similar in size to here going by № of questions asked. As for DVs on deleted QAs, my feeling is this data does include those (since it's basically "select ALL votes and vote like things, but only show me up and down") , but I would need to write another query to check that
